# Complex Join in SAS

Tags: sorting, join, merge, sas, sql-order-by

I am trying to join the following two data sets:

```
data testA;
input categorical $3. value;
*order = _n_;
datalines;
Dog. 
M  7
F  5
Cat.
M  4
F  2
;
run;

data testA;
set testA;
order=_n_;
run;

data testB;
input categorical $2. value;
datalines;
Dog. 
F  3
Cat.
M  1
F  2
;
run;

proc sql;
create table final as
select a.*,b.* from testA a left join testB b on 
a.categorical=b.categorical
order by order;
quit;
```

My desired output is the following:

```
data testA;
input categorical $ value value2;
datalines;
Dog . .
M 7 .
F 5 3
Cat . .
M 4 1
F 2 2
;
run;
```

The problems I've encountered is that 1) the 'categorical' id is not sorted alphabetically and I do not want to change its order 2) Since there are two Ms and Fs I don't know how to join without renaming the M F so that it's unique 3) It could be an inner join since what may be in value may not be in value2

Comment: Remove DOG...F from TESTA.  How are your supposed to know that you should output in MF vs FM order?  You need another information source to set the ordering.

Comment: Are you still trying to join the summary of each variable from the demographic profiles? If so, there's another option, to modify it to have all values even if it's not present.

Comment: @Reeza, yes I am still trying to join the summary from the demographic profiles. Would I alter the macro to modify those values when they aren't present?

Comment: I'll take a look this weekend and get back to you. I have another one somewhere that does it at once but its buried in the clinical trial programs so I need to find it.

Comment: @Reeza, thank you so much! I would greatly appreciate it. I was able to do the merge but it's a much more manual process than I imagine it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data has the category value as an interspersed row you will need to create a third column to hold those values when discovered as you pass through the data set. For discussion name this new column `group` -- it will also be categorical and hierarchically 'above' the other category column.  It is a 'synthetic' category that is needed for performing the complex join and will be discarded from the final result.

The `want` join will be a simple 'black box' involving grouping, coalescing, sneaky math and a group sum of a row sum.

The sample code creates a table `fulljoin_peek` that is not needed for results, but will offer insight into the data flowing through the black box.  The code also handles the 'real world data' case of a category being repeated in a group.

Sample data:

```
data testA;
input categorical $3. value;
datalines;
Dog .   * missing means categorical is really group
M  7
F  5
Cat .
M  4
F  2
Rat .   * B does not have rat
T  5
Bat .   * Bat has two M (repeated category) need to be summed
M  7
M  3
Fly .
M  5
F  6
;
run;

data testB;
input categorical $3. value;
datalines;
Dog .   * only one category
F  3
Cat .
M  1
F  2
Cow .   * A does not have cow
X  7
Bat .   * Bat has two F (repeated category) need to be summed
F  7
F  13
Fly .   * F M order different than A
F  16
M  20
;
run;
```

Augmented data has a group column and information about original ordering:

```
data A2;
  set testA;
  if value = . then do;
    * presume missing is the 'discovery' of when the 
    * group value has to be assigned;
    group = categorical; retain group;
    group_order + 1;  
    value_order = 0;
  end;
  value_order + 1;
  format group_order value_order 4.;
run;

data B2; 
  set testB;
  if value = . then do;
    * presume missing is the 'discovery' of when the 
    * group value has to be assigned;
    group = categorical; retain group; 
    group_order + 1;
    value_order = 0;
  end;
  value_order + 1;
  format group_order value_order 4.;
run;
```

Join operations (data peek)

```
* this full join shows how data matches up for the answer
* the answer will use grouping, coalescing, summing and adding;
proc sql;
  create table fulljoin_peek as
  select
    coalesce (A.categorical, B.categorical) as want_categorical
  , sum(A.value,B.value) as want_value format=4.
  , A.group as A_group
  , B.group as B_group
  , A.group_order as A_group_order
  , B.group_order as B_group_order
  , A.categorical as A_cat
  , B.categorical as B_cat
  , A.value as A_value
  , B.value as B_value
  , A.value_order as A_value_order
  , B.value_order as B_value_order
  from
    A2 as A
  full join 
    B2 as B
  on 
    A.group = B.group
    and A.categorical = B.categorical
;
```

Wanted join (answer)

```
proc sql;
  create table

    want (drop=group_order value_order) as

  select 
    coalesce (A.categorical, B.categorical) as want_categorical
  , min (coalesce (A.group_order-1e6,B.group_order)) as group_order
  , min (coalesce (A.value_order-1e6,B.value_order)) as value_order   %* -1e6 forces A order to have precedence ;
  , sum ( sum (A.value,B.value) ) as value
  from
    A2 as A
  full join 
    B2 as B
  on 
    A.group = B.group
    and A.categorical = B.categorical
  group by 
    A.group, want_categorical
  order by 
    group_order,  value_order
  ;
```